# Communication of Host in the Mininet to Host Machine Using Root Namespace

Tags: python-2.7, networking, network-programming, ping, mininet

I tried to make a connection between the host in the Mininet and the host machine (through the switch in the Mininet): (host ---> switch) --> host machine ---> Internet).

In Details:

I tried to connect the host (in the Mininet) to the host machine. I am using the Root Namespace method (among NAT, Root Namespace, OVS). I could connect the switch (in the Mininet) to the host machine, but not from the host (in the Mininet).

Not able to do `mininet> h1 ping -c 5 www.google.com`
    Error message:
    "ping: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com): Temporary failure in name resolution"

If I tried to connect other computer in the internal network like `mininet> h1 ping -c 5 192.168.3.23`
   Error message:
   "connect: Network is unreachable"

Here is my network:

[image: Network] This modified diagram is from [2](https://forum.p4.org/t/connect-mininet-hosts-to-root-namespace/91/4).

This is my snippet ("code.py"):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Reference:
#    code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62060980/5595995
#    root namespace: https://forum.p4.org/t/connect-mininet-hosts-to-root-namespace/91 

import argparse, os, pdb, sys
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSController
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost, Host, Node
from mininet.node import OVSKernelSwitch, UserSwitch
from mininet.node import IVSSwitch
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.link import TCLink, Intf
from subprocess import call
from mininet.topo import Topo


# ----- ----- ----- -----
def main(args):

    if (args.selection == "original"):
        treeNetwork()
    else:
        print ("Please, choose among choices.")


def treeNetwork():

    net = Mininet(topo=None,
                  build=False,
                  ipBase='10.0.0.0/8')

    info( '*** Adding controller\n' )
    # If error at the port 6653 holding by another contorller
    #     $ sudo fuser -k 6653/tcp
    #     ref: https://github.com/intrig-unicamp/mininet-wifi/issues/96#issuecomment-968238622
    c0=net.addController(name='c0',
                      controller=OVSController,
                      ip='127.0.0.1',
                      protocol='tcp',
                      port=6653)

    info( '*** Add switches\n')
    s1 = net.addSwitch('s1', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)

    info( '*** Add hosts\n')
    h1 = net.addHost('h1', cls=Host, ip='10.0.223.1', defaultRoute=None)
    h2 = net.addHost('h2', cls=Host, ip='10.0.223.3', defaultRoute=None)

    info( '*** Add links\n')
    s1h1 = {'bw':120,'loss':5}  # 0 (zero) not accepted
    net.addLink(s1, h1, cls=TCLink , **s1h1)

    s1h2 = {'bw':400,'loss':20}
    net.addLink(s1, h2, cls=TCLink , **s1h2)

    # from https://forum.p4.org/t/connect-mininet-hosts-to-root-namespace/91
    # To host, h1, can reachable from Terminal in host machine
    s1_node = net.getNodeByName("s1")
    root = Node('root', inNamespace=False)
    intf = net.addLink(root, s1_node).intf1
    # IP address should be under same subnet with host.
    #    Details: https://forum.p4.org/t/connect-mininet-hosts-to-root-namespace/91/6
    ip='10.0.223.0/32'  # If you need an IP address 
    root.setIP(ip, intf=intf)
    
    info( '*** Starting network\n')
    net.build()

    info( '*** Starting controllers\n')
    for controller in net.controllers:
        controller.start()

    info( '*** Starting switches\n')
    net.get('s1').start([c0])

    info( '*** Post configure switches and hosts\n')

    CLI(net)

    net.stop()


def input_para():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', action='store', dest='selection',
        help='Store a simple value')
    results = parser.parse_args()

    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':

    setLogLevel( 'info' )
    args = input_para()
    main(args)
```

(I ran this by `$ sudo python2 code.py -s original` and I don't use virtual machine nor virtual environment.)

This is when I execute `dump` at the Mininet:

```
mininet> dump
<Host h1: h1-eth0:10.0.223.1 pid=17601>
<Host h2: h2-eth0:10.0.223.3 pid=17603>
<OVSSwitch s1: lo:127.0.0.1,s1-eth1:None,s1-eth2:None,s1-eth3:None pid=17596>
<OVSController c0: 127.0.0.1:6653 pid=17588>
```

This portion of output of `$ ifconfig` in the host machine:

```
root-eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.223.0  netmask 0.0.0.0  broadcast 255.255.255.255
        inet6 fe80::ccd4:2bff:fea8:6b80  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ce:d4:2b:a8:6b:80  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 31  bytes 4173 (4.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60  bytes 11703 (11.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

With this code:
  I could ping "www.google.com" from "s1" in the Mininet: `mininet> s1 ping -c 5 www.google.com` (switch in Mininet --> host machine --> Internet)
  and
  I could also ping "10.0.223.0" (to "root-eth0" port at the "s1" in the Mininet) from the host machine `$ ping -c 5 10.0.223.0` (`ifconfig` above) (switch in Mininet <--- host machine)

The problem is:
  I couldn't ping "www.google.com" from "h1" in the Mininet: `mininet> h1 ping -c 5 www.google.com`.

#### First Try

According to [Eder's suggestion at P4 switch forum](https://forum.p4.org/t/connect-mininet-hosts-to-root-namespace/91/4), [3](https://forum.p4.org/t/connect-mininet-hosts-to-root-namespace/91/1), I have to do:

1. Execute route commands so that the host machine knows where to route packets to host within Mininet
   (if "root-eth0" IP is the same subnet, this isn't necessary)
2. Make rule in "s1" that tell the switch to forward packet to the host machine vi the port of "s1-eth5" (in my code, "s1-eth3")
3. Add ARP rules about the "root-eth0" in Mininet host and vice versa in the host machine

I guess that I did the items 1:
  Item 1: I put "h1" at 10.0.223.1 and "s1" at 10.0.223.0.

How could I do the item 2 and 3 in the Mininet (and in the host machine)?
  For the item 3, I actually tried `net.staticArp()` but the host (in the Mininet) still not able to reach the Internet.
or
Error in my code?
or
I totally miss the point?

#### Second Try

I changed the switch type from "OVSKernelSwitch" to "OVSSwitch" to "OVSBridge". It still doesn't solve the problem.

#### Third Try

Some checking with the error message of "ping: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com): Temporary failure in name resolution"

I followed [the suggestion in similar post at "ask Ubuntu"](https://askubuntu.com/a/1358237/789450) and my routing could be issue. I ran this command and here is output

```
mininet> h1 route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 h1-eth0
```

Should I modify the routing?

Thank You.

---

Reference:
  Runtime Environment
   Mininet 2.2.2
   Python 2.7
   Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04